# HttpClient cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

i'm trying to make http request in android

but i got these errors

`- HttpClient cannot be resolved to a type`

`- DefaultHttpClient cannot be resolved to a type`

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: have you added that jar?

Comment: yes, but maybe i'm done wrong! see the screen shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Delete** this line:

```
import org.apache.http.*;
```

And **Add** these:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Comment: @Nabi ATTENTION!! Remembers that httpClient class was deprecated in the API 22, you can see in this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html, now to do a httprequests uses httpUrlConnection Class, can see more info here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Answer (score 3):

This solved the problem for me: click on the project folder, then alt+Enter, go to Java Build Path, Libraries, click on add external Jar, add the .jar file located at "sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar", go to order and export and click on org.apache.http.legacy.jar,  click OK and it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

follow the following procedure:

Copy the Jar -> paste the Jar in Libs folder in Project ->  right click on jar ->  Buildpath -> add to build path.